# build and install Android source on your own Android device?

Tags: android

It is not clear to me from looking at the [page](http://source.android.com/source/building.html) on building the android source, but is it possible to build the source yourself and install it on your own device (not an emulator), e.g. a GT-N8013?

Comment: Using the ADB (Android Debug Bridge) yes, you can. An emulator communicates the exact same way as an actual device does.

Comment: @MattClark thanks, at least I know it can be done. Now, assuming someone who has never built and installed an OS before. Does http://source.android.com/source/building.html give the necessary information to build and install Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but is it possible to build the source yourself and install it on your own device (not an emulator), e.g. a GT-N8013?

All Android devices have proprietary drivers, which you would either need to get from the manufacturer (unlikely) or figure out how to copy off of your device to blend into your ROM mod. The AOSP source code is just Android.

> Does source.android.com/source/building.html give the necessary information to build and install Android?

Not for an arbitrary device like a "GT-N8013".

Comment: `AOSP` what *is* this?? I keep seeing that token show up in the terminal output after `repo sync` when I download the source.

Comment: @T.Webster: AOSP = Android Open Source Project.